# mysql - select without duplicates for every value in column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have a user table like below. How can I get only non duplicate records for each `username`? e.g. for `username = AAA`, I only want to get the row with `id = '1'` and `id ='5'`, and for `username = BBB` the row with `id = '2'`.

```
id     email            username
1      test1@test.com   AAA
2      test1@test.com   BBB
3      test2@test.com   CCC
4      test1@test.com   AAA
5      test2@test.com   AAA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.id = (
    select min(t1.id) 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.username = t.username and t1.email = t.email
)
```

With an index on `(username, id)`, this should be an efficient solution.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, another option is to use `row_number()`:

```
select id, email, username
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by username, email order by id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I want to receive all unique email values for each username. This solution will only return the line with id = '1'. For AAA username it should also return a line with id = '5', because email value is other

Comment: Since karolo22 wants id (1, 5) for AAA, wouldn't `email` also be included in the `partition by` statement?

Comment: @karolo22 if you are using GMB's second query, you can change `partition by username` to `partition by username, email`. This should give you what you need.

Comment: Maybe second query will works, but i have older version mysql - 5.7 and i can't check

Comment: @karolo22: ok. See my edited answer then.

Comment: @GMB Thanks. It works very well :)